# How to get users of current sitecollection from User Information List in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have "User Information List" and i want to get user of current site collection only but it is fetching all users of Farm.

Below is the code.

```
SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site; 

SPWeb web = currentSite.OpenWeb();

SPUserCollection userCollection = web.SiteUsers;
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any thoughts on this?